# How to add Super Filter/Filter in home page in my website?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I am using opencart version 2.2.0 and journel theme in my ecommerce site.How to add Super Filter/Filter in home page in my website?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you mean you are using Journal theme?

In left menu, go to

> Journal->Super Filter

Then click add button.
  It will allow you to add the filter to desired layout (which in your case will be Home, just choose it from the drop down list) and also define position (column left or column right), as well as set status on or off.  You can add as many as you like, in which case you can define sort order of each one. Click Save button.

I hope this helps, cheers.